# converting string to json parsing directly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, c#-4.0, kendo-ui

Can any one suggest me a way to parse string to json.String variable is holding the json data (exact json data).I want to directly return that string to my kendo grid whic take only json data.Is there a way to directly parse the string to json.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide some code samples so that others can understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library, I believe that will help.

Json.NET http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html